# Troubleshooting a Python Loop to Sum Data from Files and Rows into a List

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I'd need help in reading files and summing data to a list.
In the files all rows inclued a position and data, for example:

File 1

```
1  3,5
2  4,9
3  7,9
4  8,7
```

File 2

```
1  2,5
2  4,7
3  7,0
4  8,0
```

File 3

```
1  0,5
2  9,9
3  2,9
4  1,7
```

All lists are equally long.
I'd need to create two lists: one that includes the positions (that was easy)
BUT I'd also need to create a list where I sum all data from same position in all the files.
like: `data = [6.5, 19.5, 17.8, 18.4)`

I'd need to create a loop that goes through all files and all rows.
I already have a list where I have for example all the data from File1:
temp_list = [3.5, 4.9, 7.9, 8.7]. I'd need to sum File 2 and File 3 data to this, same positions.
I thought I'd sum this to list = [], but I cannot sum anything to an empty list.
I've now used the whole day trying to solve this :( So thanks for any help!

```
position_list = []
list = []  
temp_list = []

for row in file.readlines():
    splitted = row.strip("\n").split(" ")
    positions_list.append(float(splitted[0]))
    temp_list.append(float(splitted[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like that (I tried to reuse what you started implementing)

```
def sum_of_file(file_list):
    positions_list = []
    definitive_list = []
    for file_nt in file_list:
        temp_list = []
        with open(file_nt, 'r') as file:
            for row in file.readlines():
                splitted = row.strip("\n").split(" ")
                positions_list.append(float(splitted[0]))
                temp_list.append(float(splitted[1]))


        if len(definitive_list) == 0: # for the first time, when definitive list is still empty
            definitive_list = temp_list
        else:
            definitive_list = [i+j for i,j in zip(temp_list, definitive_list)] # else, add definitive list with the new list you've read from file
    return definitive_list


if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_list = ["./file1.txt","./file2.txt","./file3.txt"]  # file1 file2 file3
    print(sum_of_file(file_list))
```

hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

First thing to note is that the values in the files use comma as the decimal separator. We need to deal with that.

In the sample file content shown in the question the "position" is always in sequence. Let's assume that that may not be the case.

There's no need to strip the newline character because it will be ignored by the *float()* function.

Although it is noted in the question that all files are of the same length, this technique allows for this not to be the case. It also allows for the keys (positions) to be in any order within the files.

Therefore:

```
import os
from collections import defaultdict

DIR = '/Volumes/G-Drive'
FILES = 'file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt'

result = defaultdict(float)

for file in FILES:
    with open(os.path.join(DIR, file)) as data:
        for k, v in map(str.split, data):
            result[int(k)] += float(v.replace(',', '.'))

print(list(result.keys()))
print(list(result.values()))
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[6.5, 19.5, 17.8, 18.4]
```

Comment: Thanks! :) I used this one and the result seems to be correct! In reality I have over 20 files and each file has about 100 lines. But the data seems OK now. This was just a small part of my Python basics final work, and Iäm glad I'm able to continue :)

Answer (score 0):

You should consider to initialise a list like `[0, 0, 0, 0]` so you can add on it.
Or use the first file to initialize the list, then add the values from other files using a for loop with enumeration.

This works as long as all files have the same number of rows.

Also, you should consider to convert the comma separated decimal number to point separated in order to call `float()`, for example using `replace()`.

See my example, making use of:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float

Also read the comments inside the code:

```
temp_list = []

file_list = ["file_1.txt", "file_2.txt", "file_3.txt"]
for i, file_name in enumerate(file_list):
    file = open(file_name, "r")

    for n, row in enumerate(file.readlines()):
        splitted = row.strip("\n").split(" ")
        value = float(splitted[-1].replace(',', '.'))
        # if it is the first file, populate the list
        if i == 0:
            temp_list.append(value)
        # else sum the current value to index n of the list
        else:
            temp_list[n] += value
    
    file.close()

print(temp_list) #=> [6.5, 19.5, 17.8, 18.4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another suggestion if you want the code to be very compact:

```
def sum_data(self, file_list):
list_of_data = []
for file in file_list:
    with open(file, 'r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        temp_list = [list(map(float, line.strip().split()))[1] for line in lines]
        list_of_data = [i + j for i, j in zip(temp_list, list_of_data)] if list_of_data else temp_list
return list_of_data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_list = ["./your_path/file_1.txt", "./your_path/file_2.txt", "./your_path/file_3.txt"]
    list_of_data = self.sum_data(file_list)
```